# javadepend/ndepend for scala

Tags: scala, static-analysis

[JArchitect](http://www.jarchitect.com/) and [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com) are great tools for getting familiar with unknown codebases in Java and C# respectively. Are there any similar tools for Scala?

Comment: I don't know, but as a side note, JavaDepend has been renamed JArchitect  (www.JArchitect.com )

Comment: updated the question to reflect the change

Answer (score 1):

[Structure101](http://www.structure101.com) doesn't 'officially' support Scala but we are aware some of our customers are using it with Scala.

Comment: Any news regarding official Scala support?

Comment: @deamon, no immediate plans for "official" support. [Contact](http://structure101.com/contact) us directly if there's a specific issue with Scala support thru our Java release and we will take a look.